# How can I reverse the direction of arrow shown in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5qaL886d/1/

Tags: svg, d3.js

```
I want to display arrow in the reverse directions of this jsfiddle
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5qaL886d/1/

```
I an not understanding which attributes to change to do so.
Thanks in advance..
```

Comment: you should add the relevant part of your code related to the problem here (no just jsfiddle link).

Comment: Swap source and target in your input data?

Comment: thank you torazaburo..this swap idea worked fine. But if anyone can find solution to revers the arrow please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

The arrows in this snippet are drawn "by hand", i.e. the arrow points are calculated manually. So what you need to do is to recalculate them, so that they are located at the different end. Normally, the arrows are supposed to be created using "defs" (it is much easier) but in this case they seem to cause issues with IE10, therefore drawn by hand. Anyways, here is the updated version of the snippet, with arrows "reversed", but without reversing the input data. You just need to change signs here and there:

```
var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
    dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
    dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy),
    theta = Math.atan2(dy, dx) - Math.PI / 7.85,
    d90 = Math.PI / 2,
    dtxs = d.source.x + 6 * Math.cos(theta),
    dtys = d.source.y + 6 * Math.sin(theta);

return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + 
    "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 1," + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y + 
    "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 0," + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + 
     "M" + dtxs + "," + dtys +  
     "l" + (3.5 * Math.cos(d90 - theta) + 10 * Math.cos(theta)) + 
     "," + (-3.5 * Math.sin(d90 - theta) + 10 * Math.sin(theta)) + 
     "L" + (dtxs - 3.5 * Math.cos(d90 - theta) + 10 * Math.cos(theta)) + 
     "," + (dtys + 3.5 * Math.sin(d90 - theta) + 10 * Math.sin(theta)) + 
    "z";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4kmhugof/1/

Comment: Thank you very much Nikolay. This is the best solution I will ever find..thnx again :)